# Closed curve on oriented surface

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let $ C $ be a closed curve on the oriented field and $ H $ a Hamiltonian. Prove that $ X_{H} $ is somewhere tangent on C.

Comment: What have you tried? There will be no answer back to you unless you reveal it properly.